# Parsing and loading into Hive/Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

i am new to hadoop map reduce framework, and I am thinking of using hadoop map reduce to parse my data. I have thousands of big delimited files for which I am thinking of writing a map reduce job to parse those files and load them into hive datawarehouse. I have written a parser in perl which can parse those files. But I am stuck at doing the same with Hadoop map reduce

For example: I have a file like
x=a y=b z=c.....
x=p y=q z=s.....
x=1 z=2 ....
and so on

Now I have to load this file as columns (x,y,z) in hive table, but I am not able to figure out can I proceed with it. Any guidance with this would be really helpful.

Another problem in doing this is there are some files where the field y is missing. I have to include that condition in the map reduce job. So far, I have tried using  streaming.jar and giving my parser.pl as mapper as input to that jar file. I think that is not the way to do it :), but I was just trying if that would work. Also, I thought of using load function of Hive, but the missing column will create problem if I will specify regexserde in hive table.

I am lost in this now, if any one could guide me with this I would be thankful :)

Regards,
Atul

Comment: I also want to do the same thing, have you figured it out... any suggestions would be helpful, and also to add to that, if a line in the file has multiple values of x,y,z how would you club them? For example, if a line in a file has a b c d a b d a b c, I want to add a,b,c (2 times) under x,y,z in hive warehouse.. any idea on this??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I posted something a while ago to my blog a while ago. (Google "hive parse_url" should be in the top few)

I was parsing urls but in this case you will want to use `str_to_map`.

```
str_to_map(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

- `arg1` => String to process
- `arg2` => Key Value Pair separator
- `arg3` => Key Value separator

```
str = "a=1 b=42 x=abc"
str_to_map(str, " ", "=")
```

The result of `str_to_map` will give you a `map<str, str>` of 3 key-value pairs.

```
str_to_map(str, " ", "=")["a"] --will return "1"

str_to_map(str, " ", "=")["b"] --will return "42"
```

We can pass this to Hive via:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE new_table_with_cols_x_y_z
(select params["x"], params["y"], params["z"] 
 from (
   select str_to_map(raw_line," ","=") as params from data
 ) raw_line_from_data
) final_data
```

Comment: Anyone know if there is a "str_to_map" equivalent for Amazon's Elastic Map Reduce? "str_to_map" is not a defined function there.

Comment: str_to_map apparently also missing from AWS Athena.

Comment: I think `str_to_map` is Hive-specific. Also, helpful to emphasize here that the delimiter arguments of `str_to_map` are passed to `split` which means they're interpreted as regular expressions (i.e., watch out if you want to do `str_to_map(str, '|')`)

Comment: Also consider using `posexplode(str_to_map(raw_line, " ", "="))` which will automatically expand your `map` into key/value columns